# require_once("facebook-sdk/facebook.php") throws a warning "failed to open stream:Permission denied"

Tags: php, facebook, require-once

I'm trying out the tutorials for Facebook developers. However, I can't include the Facebook PHP SDK successfully in my code. As stated, `require_once("facebook_sdk/facebook.php");` throws the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(facebook_sdk/facebook.php) [function.require-once]: failed to
open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/awesome/plas.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'facebook_sdk/facebook.php'
(include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/awesome/plas.php on line 2
```

I am developing under Lucid Lynx. I tried doing `chmod 777 facebook.php` but the problem persists. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197493/require-once-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied) but the resolution arrived at (renaming the file, as it may be conflicting with one of PHP's own) does not work for me. (Come to think of it, how will a file named *facebook.php* conflict with internal PHP files?!) Even if I switch to plain `require`, the same warnings are thrown.

Curiously, if I copy the files (`facebook.php` and `base_facebook.php`) outside of `facebook_sdk` and change the `require_once` line accordingly, the require succeeds. Any thoughts?

Comment: chmod the directory as well the files are placed in. Looks like you don't have enough rights to touch files in that directory.

Comment: What's in `/opt/lampp/lib/php`? Is there a `/opt/lampp/lib/php/facebook_sdk/facebook.php` file?

Comment: You nailed it hakre. If you'd turn that to an answer, I'd gladly accept. Thanks! (--,)

Comment: possible duplicate of [require\_once failed to open stream permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197493/require-once-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server needs read access right to `facebook_sdk/facebook.php`. You can do it by `chown`ing the directory to the web server user. `chmod 777` is not a good practice.

Also make sure for each of include path, `facebook_sdk/facebook.php` exists.

Comment: Thanks for the additional "best practice" tip! Actually, I only do `chmod 777` when I'm too lazy to specify permission bits and I just want to have access. It only happens while on localhost and never on the actual server.